# Auto-Complete input field in asp.net MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to add auto-complete to input field in MVC5 project. The form located in Layout.cshtml, and i want to use autocomplete for "School" input field. so as I understand, I have made to following steps:
1. I installed jQuery UI widget via NuGet packages manager.
2. In the bottom of the layout.cshtml, I added:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`
```

3. In bundleConfig.cshtml I added:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

And also:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
"~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",             
"~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",             
"~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

4. Then, i wrote the following jQuery function:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $("#search").autocomplete({
           source: '@Url.Action("GetSchool")'
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```
5. And the GetSchool function in the HomeController:

   ```
   public JsonResult GetSchool(string term)
   {
       ReviewDBContext db = new ReviewDBContext();
       List<string> schoolsList;
       schoolsList = db.Schools.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(term)).Select(y => y.Name).ToList();
       return Json(schoolsList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```
6. finally, i added the id of the query to the layout.cshtml page:

   ```
   <li class="searchLi"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" autocomplete="on"> </li>
   ```

When I'm running the project, i got this error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

As I understood, to fix this error i need to add reference to jQuery library, so in the  tags i added the following link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And then, I got this Error:

```
 Unhandled exception at line 18, column 13 in http://localhost:*****
 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'
```

But the autocomplete function is from the jQuery UI package that i installed before.

Note 1: i got the error in internet explorer. in chrome there is not error, but the autocomplete isn't working, so i think the problem relevant for both browsers.
Note 2: I'm trying to use this tutorial http://blog.falafel.com/three-steps-use-jquery-ui-asp-net-mvc-5/

Maybe anyone know who to fix this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a Document.Ready in the following code; `<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {` - it should read `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: Can you share the line 18 of your code? And @JammoD, no that is not required in this case. Look at the `$(function () {` line of code.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Aaaah yes, I didn't realise there was a shortcut to Doument.Ready - You learn something new every day!

Comment: @JammoD this is not the problem, it possible to use both  $(document).ready.. or $(function ()

Comment: Has the script function been placed after the jQuery library has been loaded?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan the line 18 is:  </script>

Comment: @JammoD yes the jQuery library is before the function

Comment: Make sure that the object (element) is an input control.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan what does it mean? i didn't understand..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have duplicate reference of jQuery library. As per your code your view already contains jQuery reference by

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

and after the error you again added the external link of jQuery. I think that error comes by some other reason.

I believe the reason was that the `@Scripts.Render` for jQuery and jQueryUI is not in correct order. The `jQuery` must be above to jQueryUI. so try this instead.

**Replace below:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

**With:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

and remove the external reference of jQuery.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: when i remove the external reference to jQuery:
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">     </script>
i got this error: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: What about exchanging position of references?

Comment: doesn't change anything :-(

Comment: then share your complete source of page